# Missing caption prefix in figures and tables when using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, captions

I've recently switched from PDFLaTeX to XeLaTeX, and noticed that captions on my figures and tables don't have the usual "Рис." and "Таблица" prefix any more (Fig. and Table in Russian), only a number followed by a colon, or additionally a period in case of "Рис.". Is it something wrong with encoding/font?

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
  Привет!
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      x & y \\
      0 & 1
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Зашибенная таблица}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: please provide a MWE

Comment: This works with Babel version 3.9; you can try with Polyglossia, if you still don't have an up-to-date TeX system: `\usepackage{polyglossia}\setmainlanguage{russian}` instead of `\usepackage[russian]{babel}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `russian` option for `babel` didn't work with XeLaTeX for versions up to 3.8 without doing some hack.

Starting from `babel` version 3.9, the compatibility with the Russian language has been introduced.

However, there's always the alternative of using `polyglossia` with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
  Привет!
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      x & y \\
      0 & 1
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Зашибенная таблица}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output is identical if you have `babel` version 3.9 (or later) and use your original input.